# Incomplete Stanford OpenIE output

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am trying to test/run the Stanford OpenIE program using CoreNLP.

http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/openie.html

http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/openie.html

Here is my command: `java -mx1g -cp stanford-corenlp-3.6.0.jar;stanford-corenlp-3.6.0-models.jar;CoreNLP-to-HTML.xsl;slf4j-api.jar;slf4j-simple.jar edu.stanford.nlp.naturalli.OpenIE`

My input file contains the following text:

```
Born in Honolulu, Hawaii, Obama is a US Citizen.
Born in a small town, she took the midnight train going anywhere.
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
1.0 Obama   is  US Citizen
1.0 she Born in small town
1.0 she Born in town
```

I was expecting more triples such as `(Obama; born in; Honolulu, Hawaii)` and `(She; took; midnight train)` according the examples mentioned in the paper titled "Leveraging Linguistic Structure For Open Domain Information Extraction" by Angeli et al. Why is the output incomplete?

Also, what type of dependency parsing is used in OpenIE implementation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These are mistakes in the dependency parse. After the publication of the paper, we moved to Universal Dependencies, which substantially changed the underlying parsers. You can see OpenIE alongside the parses of the sentence at http://corenlp.run

In the first case, the `dep` arc from "citizen" to "born" is incorrect. In the second case, the `ccomp` edge from "took" to "going" is causing problems. This was, in the old representation, a `vmod` from "took" to "train." You can try instead the following:

```
Born in Honolulu, Obama is a US Citizen.
Born in a small town, she took the midnight train.
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.
Is there a way to use the old dependencies in the 3.6.0 version changing the annotators? 

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:
I want to extract meaningful triples such as the output of `Iron's mass is 55amu` or `Iron has mass 55amu` on http://corenlp.run. But output of `Mass of Iron is 55amu` produces _(Mass; is; 55amu)_ which is sort of meaningless. Something like _(Mass of Iron; is; 55amu)_ would've been fine. What are your thoughts on how to produce such an extraction using Stanford OpenIE?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Ah, that's a cute example. OK, in the HEAD of the GitHub repo (and on corenlp.run, modulo span visualization errors), we'll now recognize `the mass of iron is 55amu` as `(iron; mass of is; 55amu)`. The only reason the relation isn't "has mass" is to avoid having to create a dummy token for "have" -- as much as possible, OpenIE tries to maintain references to the original tokens in the sentence.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code. For, `Born in .. going anywhere`, I see that no extractions are produced because of the `ccomp` edge. But for `I am certain that he did it` also has a 'ccomp' from `certain` to `did`. It shouldn't be producing two context-less triples such as `(he; did; it)` and `(I; am; certain)` - right? 

So my issue is that I only want triples that can exist independently parsing complicated inputs such as the `..midnight train..`. Would customizing/making changes this way by editing the `clause splitter' work?

Thank you so much for your help!